# Regex for password validation and matching

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, regex

I'm trying to develop a regex expression for a password validation program that I am making with JavaScript.

**Requirements**

The password must be at least seven characters in length.

Must contain at least one

- upper case letter (A-Z)
- lower case letter  (a-z)
- number (0-9)
- special symbol (!?#@)

I'm struggling to find the right regex expression to check for all of those components. The password doesn't have to be in any specific order. I thought regex would be the easiest method for password verification, but now I'm not so sure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What things you have tried?

Comment: I thing having multiple test rather than having a messing single regex will be easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think having separate test for each case will be easier.

```
var valid = p.length > 6 && // At least 7 characters
/[a-z]/.test(p) && // At least one lowercase letter (a-z)
/[A-Z]/.test(p) && // At least one uppercase letter (A-Z)
/\d/.test(p) && // At least one number (0-9)
/[@#$%]/.test(p); // At least one special symbol
```

Comment: Try `/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/` for the special character check

Answer (score 1):

Try this I am sharing a JavaScript code:

```
function CheckPassword(inputtxt)   
{   
    var paswd = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{7,15}$/;  
    if (inputtxt.value.match(paswd))   
    {   
        alert('Correct, try another...')  
        return true;  
    }  
    else  
    {   
        alert('Wrong...!')  
        return false;  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. Separate Regex for different validation rules.

```
checkPwd = function () {
    var str = document.getElementById('password').value;
    if (str.length < 7) {
        alert("too_short");
        return ("too_short");
    } else if (str.search(/\d/) == -1) {
        alert("no_num");
        return ("no_num");
    } else if (str.search(/[a-z]/) == -1) {
        alert("no lowercase letter");
        return ("no_lowercase_letter");
    } else if (str.search(/[A-Z]/) == -1) {
        alert("no uppercase letter");
        return ("no_uppercase_letter");
    } else if (str.search(/[@#$%]/) == -1) {
        alert("no_special_character");
        return ("no_special_character");
    }
    alert("ok!!");
    return ("ok");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this am not sure this satisfy your need completely or not!!

```
/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{7,}/;

 (?=.*\d) : Check for digit

 `(?=.*[a-z])` : Check for atleast one lower case

 `(?=.*[A-Z])` : Check for atleast one upper case

{7,}        : Check for min of 7 character

(?=.*[!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]) : Check for special characters
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
/(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[^A-Za-z0-9\s]).{7}/.test(password)
```

Positive lookaheads are used to test for the "at least one of" conditions. Finally, we just make sure that 7 characters except newline can match, and we're done.

For "special symbols", we're using the negated character class `[^A-Za-z0-9\s]`, but this is obviously flexible and you can use something else that fits your needs.